# Enviar sem dar Refresh e usando onchange

Tags: javascript, formulário

Quero enviar sem dar refresh na minha pagina e usando on change estou usando o codigo abaixo

Form:

```
<form action="" id="ajax_form" method="post" >
      <input type="text" name="resultado1" size="5" onChange="envia()">
</form>
```

Script de Envio

```
jQuery('#ajax_form')(function envia() {
    var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resultados.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Olá Matheus, bem-vindo! Queres enviar os dados quando qual/quais inputs mudare(m)? Tens algum botão que faz o envio da form?

Comment: faço o envio sem o uso de botao, com o comando onChange para toda vez q o valor for alterado ele enviar, so que se uso submit(). ele da refresh na pagina, entao chamei uma função para enviar, ja tentei usar javascript e on change mas n consegui acertar o codigo

Comment: Sim, se usares `submit()` ele faz refresh à página. Podes fazer um jsFiddle para ser mais claro como o teu código está?

Comment: editei o codigo na publicação, e assim que ele esta no momento

Comment: Esse código está meio estranho... não falta nada aqui: `'#ajax_form')(function`?

Comment: ele esta assim , e que nao utilizo muito jscript entao n sei se a algo errado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer recuperar o valor do input, coloca um identificador nele. Por exemplo `id="meu_input"`

```
<input id="meu_input" type="text" name="resultado1" size="5" onChange="envia()">
    </form>
```

Ai então, busque o valor desse input pelo ID. Assim:

```
$.post("resultados.php",{resultado1: $("#meu_input").val()},function(){});
```

Só modifiquei o seu código, não tenho certeza se utilizar dessa forma o evento, ira funcior, já que você está utilizando JQuery, eu recomendo que você pegue o evento `change`, dessa forma (Após definir o ID):

```
$("#meu_input").change(function(event){
    alert($(event.target).val());
});
```

Aplicando o envio, do seu código:

```
$("#meu_input").change(function(event){
    $.post("resultados.php",{resultado1: $(event.target).val()},function(){});
});
```

Comment: ja estou usando o id valor, e n funiona

Comment: Mas o evento dispara? Já colocou um "alert" dentro da função envia, para ver se o problema está no envio, ou na chamada da função?

Comment: o problema esta na chamada da função, ja fiz isto

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, dessa forma deve funcionar.

Comment: funcionou 100% vlw mesmo